# Database connection Error while hosting site on heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, github, heroku

So I was trying to host my first Django app on heroku.
Took help form some Youtube channels. I used postgresql as my database. Now when I tried hosting my app on heroku the following error is showing up:

````
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?```
**This is the error showing**
````

Comment: Where is your database hosted?

Comment: Are you using Mac?

Comment: I am using Windows for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`run postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` The result of this should be:

```
    FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
     HINT:   Is another postmaster (PID 379) running in data directory 

"/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

Then type `kill -9 PID in HINT`

Let me know if this works for you?

Comment: Do I run the code in command prompt? I am a newbie in Django. Embarrassed to ask such questions anyways.

Comment: That's fine. Run it in your terminal